Angular material Custom theme not working in angular 18
While installing the material module the default theme was added as below
        "styles": [
          "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],

Using the reference https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme

A custom theme was created as below
// This file was generated by running 'ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme'.
// Proceed with caution if making changes to this file.
@use 'sass:map';
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

// Note: Color palettes are generated from primary: #a78bfa, secondary: #e6e6e6
$_palettes: (
  primary: (
    0: #000000,
    10: #21005e,
    20: #381385,
    25: #432390,
    30: #4f319c,
    35: #5b3ea8,
    40: #674bb5,
    50: #8065d0,
    60: #9b7fed,
    70: #b59cff,
    80: #cebdff,
    90: #e8ddff,
    95: #f5eeff,
    98: #fdf7ff,
    99: #fffbff,
    100: #ffffff,
  ),
  secondary: (
    0: #000000,
    10: #001f24,
    20: #00363d,
    25: #00424a,
    30: #004f58,
    35: #005b66,
    40: #006874,
    50: #008391,
    60: #00a0b0,
    70: #22bccf,
    80: #4fd8eb,
    90: #97f0ff,
    95: #d0f8ff,
    98: #edfcff,
    99: #f6feff,
    100: #ffffff,
  ),
  tertiary: (
    0: #000000,
    10: #31101e,
    20: #492533,
    25: #56303e,
    30: #633b49,
    35: #704655,
    40: #7d5261,
    50: #996a79,
    60: #b58393,
    70: #d19dad,
    80: #efb8c9,
    90: #ffd9e3,
    95: #ffecf0,
    98: #fff8f8,
    99: #fffbff,
    100: #ffffff,
  ),
  neutral: (
    0: #000000,
    10: #1c1b1e,
    20: #313033,
    25: #3d3b3e,
    30: #48464a,
    35: #545156,
    40: #605d62,
    50: #79767a,
    60: #938f94,
    70: #aeaaae,
    80: #cac5ca,
    90: #e6e1e6,
    95: #f4eff4,
    98: #fdf8fd,
    99: #fffbff,
    100: #ffffff,
    4: #0f0e11,
    6: #141316,
    12: #201f23,
    17: #2b292d,
    22: #363438,
    24: #3a383c,
    87: #ddd8dd,
    92: #ece7eb,
    94: #f1ecf1,
    96: #f7f2f7,
  ),
  neutral-variant: (
    0: #000000,
    10: #1d1a22,
    20: #322f38,
    25: #3d3a43,
    30: #48454e,
    35: #54515a,
    40: #605d66,
    50: #79757f,
    60: #938f99,
    70: #aea9b4,
    80: #cac4cf,
    90: #e6e0ec,
    95: #f5eefa,
    98: #fdf7ff,
    99: #fffbff,
    100: #ffffff,
  ),
  error: (
    0: #000000,
    10: #410002,
    20: #690005,
    25: #7e0007,
    30: #93000a,
    35: #a80710,
    40: #ba1a1a,
    50: #de3730,
    60: #ff5449,
    70: #ff897d,
    80: #ffb4ab,
    90: #ffdad6,
    95: #ffedea,
    98: #fff8f7,
    99: #fffbff,
    100: #ffffff,
  ),
);

$_rest: (
  secondary: map.get($_palettes, secondary),
  neutral: map.get($_palettes, neutral),
  neutral-variant: map.get($_palettes,  neutral-variant),
  error: map.get($_palettes, error),
);
$_primary: map.merge(map.get($_palettes, primary), $_rest);
$_tertiary: map.merge(map.get($_palettes, tertiary), $_rest);

$light-theme: mat.define-theme((
  color: (
    theme-type: light,
    primary: $_primary,
    tertiary: $_tertiary,
  ),
));
$dark-theme: mat.define-theme((
  color: (
    theme-type: dark,
    primary: $_primary,
    tertiary: $_tertiary,
  ),
));

Included the theme in the style.scss file
@use './m3-theme' as customTheme;
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

html {
  // Apply the light theme by default
  @include mat.core-theme(customTheme.$light-theme);
}

However, still not working getting the default theme

The toolbar is using the color primary
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  
</mat-toolbar>


The reason is, adding the color="primary" attribute to <mat-toolbar> is no longer supported by the material 3 version of theming.  Adding color variants via attributes no longer works for all components which used to use them.  Per the API doc for the toolbar:
 @Input()

color: string | null
    

Theme color of the toolbar. This API is supported in M2 themes only, it has no effect in M3 themes.

You will need to add a custom class in a mixin (globally) or in the components style file (encapsulated).  So in this case, if lets say we want to have a global class which adds the primary color from our theme and adds that color as the background color and its contrast color as the text color;  We could add a mixin which contains this global class:
/app/styles/mixins/_global-styles.scss // make sure to make mixins sass partials by starting the file name with an underscore
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@mixin global-styles-theme($theme) {
  $primary: mat.get-theme-color($theme, primary);
  $on-primary: mat.get-theme-color($theme, on-primary); // make sure to include mat.system-level-colors(theme.$light-theme) in your styles.scss for this to work

  // add global styles here
  .primary {
    background: $primary;
    color: $on-primary;
  }
}

Then in your styles.scss you would include this mixin along with all your other theme initialization methods:
src/styles.scss
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use './app/styles/theme' as theme;
@use './app/styles/mixins/global-styles' as gs;
@include mat.core;

html {
  @include mat.core-theme(theme.$light-theme);
  @include mat.all-component-themes(theme.$light-theme);
  @include mat.system-level-colors(
    theme.$light-theme
  );
  @include gs.global-styles-theme(theme.$light-theme);
}

now in your component template, give this class to whatever you want to have a primary background and the correct contrasting text color:
<mat-toolbar class="primary"></mat-toolbar>

for more info check out these docs, which also describes how to do color variants for other components:  https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-component-color-variants.

I followed the same steps as you, here is the global-styles.scss that worked for me, please note: I removed the default scss added by angular material and included the custom theme and it started working
Add angular material
ng add @angular/material

Then create the custom theme
ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme

Then remove the default CSS added by angular material in angular.json
        "outputPath": "dist/demo",
        "scripts": [],
        "styles": ["src/global_styles.scss"],
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json"

Then finally modify the global styles to use the new theme
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use './m3-theme' as customTheme;

body {
  @include mat.all-component-themes(customTheme.$light-theme);
  font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

@include mat.core();
@include mat.color-variants-backwards-compatibility(customTheme.$light-theme);

Stackblitz Demo

I did still not working

Try this, the toolbar should be full color, however it is white.  
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="aboveMenu">Above
 I have tried on your solution, it didn't work

So I had this same issue and was able to get it working.
I couldn't find anything online so I searched into material angular's files to see how theirs was working and found this at the top of their _palettes.scss
I copied it over to my auto-generated theme and put it at the top of the file.
I made my _palettes into a $my-palette non-private variable and removed the tertiary piece in that object. Important to note here you would call those copied over functions. Also notice how there is no "primary" anymore.
 $my-pallete: _apply_patches((
   0: ...,
   100: ...,
   secondary: (...),
   neutral: (...),
   neutral-variant: (...),
 ));

I also remove the @use '@angular/material' as mat; from the file and $_rest variable at the bottom. I then moved the mat.define-theme(...) section to the styles.scss using my now non private palette and it works now.
@use 'sass:color';

@use 'sass:map';

@use 'sass:math';


/// Estimate a hue using the given previous and next hues.

@function _estimate-hue($hues, $hue, $prev-hue, $next-hue) {

  $weight: math.div($next-hue - $hue, $next-hue - $prev-hue) * 100%;

  @return color.mix(map.get($hues, $prev-hue), map.get($hues, $next-hue), $weight);

}

 

// TODO(mmalerba): Remove this and add correct values for these hues.

/// The Material Design spec references some neutral hues that are not generated by

/// https://m3.material.io/theme-builder. For now we use this function to estimate the missing hues

/// by blending the nearest hues that are generated.

/// Note: when updating, the corresponding logic in the theme generation schematic should be

/// updated as well. See `src/material/schematics/ng-generate/m3-theme/index.ts#patchMissingHues`

@function _patch-missing-hues($palette) {

  $neutral: map.get($palette, neutral);

  $palette: map.set($palette, neutral, 4, _estimate-hue($neutral, 4, 0, 10));

  $palette: map.set($palette, neutral, 6, _estimate-hue($neutral, 6, 0, 10));

  $palette: map.set($palette, neutral, 12, _estimate-hue($neutral, 12, 10, 20));

  $palette: map.set($palette, neutral, 17, _estimate-hue($neutral, 17, 10, 20));

  $palette: map.set($palette, neutral, 22, _estimate-hue($neutral, 22, 20, 25));

  $palette: map.set($palette, neutral, 24, _estimate-hue($neutral, 24, 20, 25));

  $palette: map.set($palette, neutral, 87, _estimate-hue($neutral, 87, 80, 90));

  $palette: map.set($palette, neutral, 92, _estimate-hue($neutral, 92, 90, 95));

  $palette: map.set($palette, neutral, 94, _estimate-hue($neutral, 94, 90, 95));

  $palette: map.set($palette, neutral, 96, _estimate-hue($neutral, 96, 95, 98));

  @return $palette;

}

 

/// Adds the error colors to the given palette.

@function _patch-error-palette($palette) {

  @return map.merge(

    $palette,

    (

      error: (

        0: #000000,

        10: #410002,

        20: #690005,

        25: #7e0007,

        30: #93000a,

        35: #a80710,

        40: #ba1a1a,

        50: #de3730,

        60: #ff5449,

        70: #ff897d,

        80: #ffb4ab,

        90: #ffdad6,

        95: #ffedea,

        98: #fff8f7,

        99: #fffbff,

        100: #ffffff,

      ),

    )

  );

}

 

@function _apply-patches($palette) {

  @return _patch-missing-hues(_patch-error-palette($palette));

}


Followed multiple solutions and answers and researched a lot into this. Nothing seemed to work. The only time angular picked up the theme colours were if I used the prebuilt theme css. So I copied one the prebuilt css and Ctrl-Replaced the colors with my own corresponding theme colours. Took 15 minutes but now I have the results I need.
Step 1:
Copy the contents of any prebuilt theme. I copied @angular\material\prebuilt-themes\magenta-violet.css as it a dark theme.
Step 2:
Find the magenta-violet palette in node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/_palettes.scss
Step 3:
Find the hue tone defined in the palette and the corresponding hue tone in your custom theme.
Step 4:
Find and Replace the hue tone in the copied file to your custom hue tone. You will find that not all the hue tones are used anyway. And you will need to replace only a few of them.

Would you please create a demo at Stackblize?

Just add the last two lines to also have the colors too.
html {
  @include mat.core-theme(m3-theme.$light-theme);
  @include mat.all-component-themes(m3-theme.$light-theme);
  @include mat.system-level-colors(m3-theme.$light-theme);
  @include mat.system-level-typography(m3-theme.$light-theme);
}

